# Is writing multiple (non-iterator) conditions in C# for loop bad practice (code smell)?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I wonder if it is OK to replace this code

```
bool finished = (some_initial_conditions);
int i = 1;
while (!finished && i < 100)
{
    some_commands;
    if (some_condition)
        finished = true;
    int++;
}
```

with this code:

```
bool finished = (some_initial_conditions);
for (int i = 1; !finished && i < 100; i++)
{
    some_commands;
    if (some_condition)
        finished = true;
}
```

Is there some reason for not adding additional conditions to for loop?

Edit: To be more clear, this is full code of the function

```
public static string UnquoteString(string str, char quote)
{
    var isUnquotable = (str.Length > 1 && str[0] == quote && str[str.Length - 1] == quote);

    for (int i = 1; isUnquotable && i < str.Length - 2; i++)        //  skip first and last chars == quote
    {
        if (str[i] == quote)
        {
            if (i < str.Length - 3 && str[i + 1] == quote)
                i++;
            else
                isUnquotable = false;
        }
    }
    var commentQuote = (quote == '\'') ? '"' : '\'';

    if (!isUnquotable)
        throw new InvalidStringException($"Error! String {commentQuote}{str}{commentQuote} " +
                                         $"is NOT unqotable with char {commentQuote}{quote}{commentQuote} acting as a quote");

    return str[1..(str.Length - 2)].Replace(string.Concat(quote, quote), quote.ToString());
}
```

I need to know wether the loop was ended with a break or not in order to know should I throw exception.

I could use @Charlieface's answer and forcefully exit the for loop with a throw instead of break, but then I would have to duplicate throw for failing to comply with initial condition.

Comment: It is uncommon but not wrong per se. I would prefer the first one but that's an opinion

Comment: technically, there's no problem with this. but conventionally, for-loops are used when you _know_ beforehand how often a loop runs. using a for-loop that's based on something that could change "at random" is unexpected, and should be avoided. (that being said: this question is off-topic since it's purely opinion-based) (and if you still want a for-loop with this extra-end condition, i'd personally prefer a `break` inside the loop)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to repeat the loop 99 times instead of 100?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - That is not relevant here, everything here is arbitrary psudo-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of those constructs is idiomatic. A `while` implies an indefinite loop which only breaks on some arbitrary condition, and the second is rather unusual.

Normally when you have a counter condition you always use a `for` loop, and then use `break` inside the loop.

```cs
if (some_initial_conditions)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        some_commands;
        if (some_condition)
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Given your new edits, you can change your function like this, bailing out out of the loop using `throw`. To prevent duplicating code you can place that in a function (or a local function as I have done).

```cs
public static string UnquoteString(string str, char quote)
{
    if (str.Length <= 1 || str[0] != quote || str[str.Length - 1] != quote)
        ThrowIsUnquoteable();

    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length - 2; i++)        //  skip first and last chars == quote
    {
        if (str[i] == quote)
        {
            if (i < str.Length - 3 && str[i + 1] == quote)
                i++;
            else
                ThrowIsUnquoteable();
        }
    }

    return str[1..(str.Length - 2)].Replace(string.Concat(quote, quote), quote.ToString());


    void ThrowIsUnquoteable()
    {
        var commentQuote = (quote == '\'') ? '"' : '\'';
        throw new InvalidStringException($"Error! String {commentQuote}{str}{commentQuote} is NOT unqotable with char {commentQuote}{quote}{commentQuote} acting as a quote");
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally yes, but I need preserved state of ```finished``` variable in the next part of code where I decide should I throw exception

Comment: See new edit...

Comment: I wrote very similar version to yours except that I have made two omissions. Firstly I didn't put ```var commentQuote =...``` statement in the sub-function together with throw, but left it in the main function. Secondly I made first statement in the form ```if () for... else throw```. On the other hand you forget to put logical not in the first if statement :-). So it is 2:1 for you. Thanks for your effort

Comment: First if should be ```if (str.Length <= 1 || str[0] != quote || str[str.Length - 1] != quote)```